# Build light weight FFMPEG lib for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I need to make movie (MP4) using sequence of bitmaps. I am using Jcodec it's working fine but if i share the video which one is builded using Jcodec, it's not supported by whatsapp. So i plan to make the movie from ffmpeg (Prebuilt libraries https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) it's working fine. But my universal apk size was increased up to (50mb). I just need to make movie from sequance of images so i don't need any external libraries and audio features also. So please help me someone to build the ffmpeg for only convert the sequance images to video only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some [packages](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/tree/master/src) like an opus.
probably you don't need all future.

you should change [this file](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/blob/master/android.sh)